# add the string value for multi array

Tags: c#

i want to add the string value for array using pointer in C#. it look like the code as below:

```
public static string[,] Matrixgroup = new string[199, 3];

void a()
{
    string*[0,0] Matrixgroup = {"A"};
}
```

can anybody here help me?

Comment: Are you want something like `Matrixgroup[0,0] = "A"`?

Comment: *Matrixgroup[0,0] = "A"; i want to make it like this

Comment: There aren't really pointers in C#, are you perhaps coming from a C/C++ background?

Comment: yes, i'm member of C/C++. now i'm learning C#. so i didnot know how to convert this code to C#.

Comment: Do you just want a two dimensional array of strings?

Comment: yes. im using dimension array

Answer (score 0):

Unlike you will have seen in your C/C++ background, `string` has become it's own type. You can stop thinking of strings as pointers to character arrays: they are now a specific type.

I think you are just trying to initialize one of the strings, which you could do like this...

```
    string[,] Matrixgroup = new string[199, 3];
    Matrixgroup[0,0]= "A";
```

But it might be useful to know that you can initialise them all at once (if you know all the values), as shown in [multidimensional arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays).

Comment: @robert As a new user, you may want to take a moment to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)